# Elasticsearch Geoquery Show No Results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a geoquery between two indexes.

The first index contains documents with geo points. I can see this documents in a Coordinated map without any problem. It has the next mapping

```
PUT cuartos_mexico/ 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "geo": {
        "properties": {
          "coordinates": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The second index is geopolygon with the next mapping

```
PUT zones/
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "geo_shape"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I am indexing the documents like this

```
POST zone/_doc/1
{
    "zone":"First Zone",
        "location" : {
            "type":"multipolygon",
            "coordinates":[[[[-99.1766242668,19.4202738509],[lots of coordinates],[-99.1766242668,19.4202738509]]]]
    }   
}
```

When I try to the following query:

```
GET cuartos_mexico/_search
{
  "query":{
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": {
        "indexed_shape": {
          "index": "zonas",
          "id":    1,
          "path":  "location"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got this error:

```
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "failed to find geo_shape field [location]",
        "index_uuid": "7RxmHAWPQNGprsu72af4sw",
        "index": "cuartos_mexico"
      }
```

I wanted to do this geoquery so I didn't have to pass the coordinates like the query below which works fine but there are lots of coordinates and makes it hard to read

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "fecha_insercion": {
              "gte": "2018-01-01",
              "lte": "2018-01-31"
              }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "geo_polygon": {
          "geo.coordinates": {
            "points": [
              [
                -99.2174431026,
                19.4447686839
              ],
        [lots of doordinates]
              [
                -99.2174431026,
                19.4447686839
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And it returns the documents with no problem.

Comment: You create the `zones` index (i.e. `PUT zones`) but then you store a document into the `zone` index (i.e. `POST zone/_doc/1`). Also you're trying to query index `"index": "zonas"` with your `indexed_shape` query...

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it to work. Do you know if its possible to use two indexed shapes ??. Thanks again.